# Scanning ProgressBar

Tags: android

I'm developing wizard kind screens for my application, where user will provide some data which will be send to a server. When user is waiting for response I wish to have a loader like android shows for the device first time setup. It's green (or blue) chunks of running stripes.
Does anybody know how to bring them to my app desirably from android's style themes without doing custom animation?

[image: Device setup screen]

Comment: This may only be tangentially relevant, but are you using AsyncTask to upload your data? If you're transferring data to/from a server, you should always do that on a separate thread than the UI.

Comment: @Stephen of course I do network request in a separate thread, otherwise I would get "NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Comment: I've never heard of this "NetworkOnMainThreadException" before, probably because it's been at least a year since I've programmed natively for Android. Looks like I'm way out of touch now.

Comment: @Stephen Android Team added this exception throwing since SDK11(3.0) in previous releases network request will just freeze UI thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THat must be a ProgressBar.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/scanning_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" />
```

Comment: Works exactly as it should be. Thanks